# How can I receive shadows on an image-plane and at the same time ignore incoming lights? (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image, transparency

In the Image below I've placed some 'feathers' on top of each other.
They are made of image-planes with transparent backgrounds.

[image: feather shadow test]

**The problem I have** is that I would like the feathers to receive shadows from other feathers. However I don't want them to catch lights (which happens on the left where I've added a strong spot-light)

*The feathers on the left have these node-settings* (which reflects lights and shadows, and also casts them):
[image: node editor feathers left]

*And the feathers on the right have these...* 
(which ignore lights and shadows, but do however cast shadows on other objects)
[image: node editor feathers right]

The ideal thing would be to have the node-settings something like the feathers on the right *(seen in the last picture)*, but that the image-plane also can receive a shadow.

**Is it possible to achieve this using only the node-editor?**  *(or do I have to use render layers?! I'm not sure how to do that either...)*

If someone knows a good way to solve this, please let me know! :)